# how do I write a literal for the class of an array of an arbitrary class

Tags: java, reflection, literals

How do I use literals to define parameter types for java.lang.Class.getMethod?

```
    public class NewTester
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {   
            System.out.println("START");
            Worker myWorker = new Worker();
            Thing[] argument = new Thing[] { new Thing("book"), 
                                             new Thing("pencil") };
            Object[] arguments = new Object[] { argument };

                            // HOW ABOUT LITERALS HERE INSTEAD OF getClass
            Class<?>[] parameterTypes = new Class<?>[] { argument.getClass() }; 

            Method myMethod;
            try
            {
              myMethod = myWorker.getClass().getMethod("work", parameterTypes);
            } 
            catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e)
            {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            try
            {
              myMethod.invoke(myWorker, arguments);
            } 
            catch (IllegalAccessException | 
                   IllegalArgumentException | 
                   InvocationTargetException e)
            {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println("END");
        }

        private static class Worker
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void work(Thing[] argument)
            {
                assert argument.length == 2;
                assert argument[0].value.equals("book");
                assert argument[1].value.equals("pencil");
            }
        }

        private static class Thing
        {
            String value;
            Thing(String value)
            {
                this.value = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried the following but it fails in the getMethod call with a NoSuchMethodException.

```
Class<?>[] parameterTypes = new Class<?>[] { java.lang.reflect.Array.class };
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but it looks like you may be searching for `Thing[].class`.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I didn't think that would work because of my compulsion to use parentheses. `(Thing[]).class` did not compile. Yours does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `Class` literal representing some `Type` you can write `Type.class`.

For arrays use `Type[].class`.